# How to show two divs on mouse over on the first div and hide the same two divs on mouse out

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have one div where i am showing my game name(div2)
When a user moves her mouse on this(div2) then two divs(div1 & div3) should open on at the same

**what divs(div1 & div3) will contains:**

- div1 should show small image of my game, whereas
- div3 should show small description about my game.

**Position of divs**:

- div2 should be visible in second row.(In the middle  of the two divs div1 & div3)
- div1 should be visible on the top.(game image)
- div3 should be visible on the bottom.

And also when user mouse out their cursor from div1 & div3 then Both these divs should hide and remain open the div2.

I tried to solve my problem with my below code But it did't help me at all.
Please check my code below and suggest me a good solution for my problem.

My code:

```
       <html>
            <head>
                <title>This example will showw game description on over the game link (above div will show game image and below will show game details info)</title>
        <link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>  
        <script>

        $(document).ready(function(){
          $("#d1").hover(function()
          {
            $("#d1").hide();
             $("#d2").show();
              $("#d3").show();
          });

           $("#maindiv").mouseout(function()
          {
            $("#d1").show();
             $("#d2").hide();
              $("#d3").hide();
          });
        });

        </script>
        </head>

        <body>
            <div id="maindiv">
            <div id="d1">Tic Tac Toe(This should hide on mouse over this div)</div>
            <div id="d2" style="display: none;"> <img src="http://www.infosys.com/SiteCollectionImages/cloud-ecosystem-hub-mm.jpg" title=" Image of Tic tac toe small image" /></div>
        </div> 
             <div id="d3" style="display: none;">
                 <table width="80px" height="26px" border="1">
                     <tr>
                          <td width="200px"> Information/description about tic tac toe in small para. blah blah blah  </td>
                     </tr>
                 </table>

             </div>

        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: Your code seems to work for me? The only thing that's a little weird is the div is kinda small so you have to find the sweet spot for hovering over so that the image and the description show. Can you be a little more specific on what is not working? I ran it in Chrome.

Comment: @aug I am trying to implement like this(check [this-click here](http://www.infosys.com/pages/index.aspx) link and on the button of page you will find 4 images ,on mouse over of it,they shows info)

Comment: @aug But my code is not stylish and it is not showing my div2 on the middle of the div1 & div3.And also my code is not accurate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this: http://jsbin.com/uyoxip/1/edit

```
  <div id="maindiv" style='margin:0 auto; width:100%;'>
       <div id="d2" style="display: none; float:left; width:500px;"> 
            <img src="http://www.infosys.com/SiteCollectionImages/cloud-ecosystem-hub-mm.jpg" title=" Image of Tic tac toe small image" />
       </div>
       <div id="d1" style='float:left; width:500px;'>
            Tic Tac Toe(This should hide on mouse over this div)
       </div>
       <div id="d3" style="display: none; float:left; width:500px;">
             <table width="80px" height="26px" border="1">
                 <tr>
                    <td width="200px"> 
                       Information/description about tic tac toe in small para. blah blah blah  
                    </td>
                 </tr>
             </table>
          </div>
       </div>
```

script:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#maindiv").hover(function(){

         $("#d2").stop().slideDown();
         $("#d3").stop().slideDown();
         $("#d1").stop().slideUp();

      },function(){

        $("#d1").stop().slideDown();
        $("#d2").stop().slideUp();
        $("#d3").stop().slideUp();
      });
    });
```

Comment: One problem, why this info  "Tic Tac Toe(This should hide on mouse over this div)" is not hiding when the two divs(d2 & d3) are showing.

Comment: @AshutoshSingh  just uncomment this line: $("#d1").hide();

Comment: Now its fine. Is it possible to animate this nicely. While opening divs it should open with good animation. And same while it closes.

Comment: if i puts slideUp() & slideDown() then the code is not functioning properly. Please check it and let me know the solution.

Comment: This is fine then before. But still there is so much gap between the img div and info div.

Comment: this is done check again and accept it as answer to your question:http://jsbin.com/uyoxip/7/edit

Comment: Yes now its done. Thank you. Now i defiantly accept it as my answer.